# What is the solution for "Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am running Firefox version 19 in grid
Hub-Mac machine
Node- Windows Vista

```
while setting node in windows i used "-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=<path of firefox19-bin>"
```